# Expanding a macro into a long list for use with pgfplotstable

Tags: macros, pgfplotstable

Failing again to get macros to work. I have the following M(n)WE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\xdef\mydef{
\foreach \a/\b in {3/0,3/2,10/2,20/2,24/0,25/2}{%
every row no \a\  col no \b/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{{##1}}}},}
}}

\pgfplotstableset{\mydef}
\end{document}
```

and I'm trying to produce

```
\pgfplotstableset{
every row no 3 col no 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
every row no 3 col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
every row no 10 col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
every row no 20 col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
every row no 24 col no 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
every row no 25 col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}}
}
```

I'd love to say I have some glimmering of what I'm doing wrong but I have to confess that I absolutely don't. Any help very gratefully received.

As an aside is there an easy way to pass a list as an argument to a `\def` or `\xdef` macro? That would make the final macro a lot more functional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\xdef` command only does *expansion* on the replacement text; it doesn't *execute* assignments, which are necessary for the `\foreach` cycle to work.

The way out is to build `\mydef` by accretion. Since you also need `#` in the replacement text, token registers seem the best candidate:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\toks1={} % initialize the register to empty
\foreach \a/\b in {3/0,3/2,10/2,20/2,24/0,25/2}{%
  \edef\temp{\the\toks1
    every row no \a\  col no \b/.style={postproc cell
      content/.style={@cell content=\noexpand\fbox{####1}}},}%
  \global\toks1=\expandafter{\temp}
}
\edef\mydef{\the\toks1}

\pgfplotstableset{\mydef}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\the\toks1` will only expand once in the `\edef`: by rule, the contents of the token register is delivered but not expanded any more. You have to double the `#` twice, so that it will end up "singly doubled" in the final replacement text. In the `\edef\temp` stage, `\a` and `\b` will be expanded, but not `\fbox` (this would be disastrous).

Here's what I get from `\show\mydef` (end of lines added for clarity):

```
> \mydef=macro:
->every row no 3\ col no 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},
every row no 3\ col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},
every row no 10\ col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},
every row no 20\ col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},
every row no 24\ col no 0/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},
every row no 25\ col no 2/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox {##1}}},.
```

---

An abstraction of this can be as follows:

```
\newcommand{\pashaset}[2]{%
  \toks1={}%
  \foreach \a/\b in {#2}{%
    \edef\temp{\the\toks1
      every row no \a\  col no \b/.style={postproc cell
        content/.style={@cell content=\noexpand\fbox{########1}}},}%
    \global\toks1=\expandafter{\temp}}%
  \edef#1{\the\toks1}%
}
```

Then you can call

```
\pashaset{\mydef}{3/0,3/2,10/2,20/2,24/0,25/2}
```

and `\mydef` would be defined as before. Notice that the `#` must be doubled up again, since now they appear in the replacement text of a definition.

What happens with them? When TeX stores the definition, two consecutive `#` are reduced to one. So the replacement text actually contains `####1`. When the replacement text is used in the `\edef`, they become two, as required.

Comment: thanks @egreg. That is perfect. I'm not sure I understand the doubling rule, can you explain it further or tell me where I'd go to clarify it? Also .. can't think of a better person to ask.. do you know if there is a way of passing a list like that to a macro? So if I wanted to, I could define that script as a command?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha I'm not sure to understand what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi @egreg so if in the example above I wanted to set it up as `\newcommand\mycommand...{all your code above}` so that I could just write \mycommand{3/0,24/0} for example and get the same result. Is there a way to tell \newcommand to expect \mycommand to take a list argument?